# Setting alpha to 0 to remove animation? -objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, alpha, uiviewanimation

I'm developing an iOS application and I have a simple question.

If you start an animation for an image (like rotating it) for an unlimited time, and then after a few seconds set the alpha to zero to hide it `[[self image]setAlpha:0];`. Is the animation still working in the background or not? Do you always have to set `[layer removeAllAnimations];`? I'm asking this because I don't wan't to slow down the cpu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to use `removeAllAnimations`, not just setting the `alpha` to zero. If you use a timer or display link to monitor the `presentationLayer` (which indicates the current properties of the view) of the animated object, you'll see that the animation is still in progress, even if the `alpha` is zero.